# How to cross out text with dotted bar line?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

How to cross out text with dotted bar line or draw it above the text in label or alertview?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tutorial will help you:
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/